# Inserting million of records into a file

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I want to insert million of records into a file using oracle and without using a loop or java code.

while browsing I found something as util_file in oracle which is used to record rows into file but was unable to use it. can some please help me in understanding or writing the code to write the resultset returned by a select query into a file or even a procedure would even work.

I tried below procedure it run successfully but doesnot create file with data

```
  create or replace procedure familydetails 
       ( p_file_dir IN varchar2, p_filename IN varchar2 ) 
      IS v_filehandle utl_file.file_type; 
       cursor family Is  
       select * from fmly_detl  
       begin 
       v_filehandle :=utl_file.fopen('C:\tempfolder','sqltest.txt','W'); 
       utl_file.new_line(v_filehandle); 
       for fmly IN fmly_detl LOOP 
       utl_file.putf(v_filehandle,'family %s details:s\n',fmly.last_name,fmly.first_name,fmly.indv_id);   
       end loop;
      utl_file.put_line(v_filehandle,'END OF REPORT'); 
       UTL_FILE.fclose(v_filehandle); 
       end familydetails;
```

Comment: What possible reason could you have for disallowing the use of loops?  If you want to write to a file, you'll need procedural code.  Procedural code uses loops.

Comment: I donot want to write a loop because the select query would return more than 10million of records and I want to make the process fast if I write a loop then have to repeat all the 10million+ records one by one and insert into the file and this is my first time working with procedures so I am not sure how they work sorry but as per my understanding I was thinking procedures performance will be fast when compared with a sql with loop to write it into a file, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Why were you unable to use `utl_file`? If you have a specific problem with code you wrote using that then add your code and errors to the question. How and where will you invoke this process? Is the file going to be on the server or on a client? What format will the data be in?

Comment: @user3124277 - Writing 10 million rows of data to a flat file is going to be relatively slow.  If you want to do it in PL/SQL, you'll need a loop that iterates over all the rows.  You could `BULK COLLECT` the data (with a `LIMIT`) in a loop to make things a bit faster but I can pretty much guarantee that context shifts are not going to be a substantial proportion of your processing time.

Comment: @ alex the file is in text format and I actually haven't tried imlementing util_file, tried looking into lots of examples but it was confusing and difficult for me to understand since this is my first project with such extensive sqls with large amount of data and I am trying to make it efficient

Comment: @Justin I have one whole day of time to run the job so wont that be sufficient to record all the data into file and can you help me with utl_file using procedures please, will this wnt be atleast some what better in performance then using one by one row and saving it into the file using java code

Comment: Data will be read from the DB into a buffer whether you're using SQL or PL/SQL or Java; you can tweak the array size to tune that. And data will be written to disk in a buffer whether you're using `utl_file` or Java to write it out. You seem to be optimising rather prematurely. If you don't understand the `utl_file` examples you've already seen, would you understand it if someone tried again here? We can't write a procedure to your spec for you, you have to put some effort in, or you won't understand or learn.

Comment: @Alex ok let me give a try and implement it, thanks

Comment: @user3124277 tried my best, to help you! Check my answer! Good Luck!

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried running the procedure it is successful but not creating any data into the file, please let me know if I am doing something wrong

Comment: @user3124277 Your have to use one of the value in directory_name of all_directories table;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if you use sqlplus in unix.. Here is a simple solution, put the below as a script_name.ksh and execute it (ksh script_name.ksh)

```
sqlplus -s user_id/password@sid << ! >> ~/sql_output.txt

set feedback off;
set pages 0;
set linesize 20000;
set arraysize 1000;
set tab  off;
--Your Query, with proper padding , or comma seprated
--Eg Select employee_id||'|'||employee_name||'|'||employee_age
--   from employee;

!
```

2) If you use a IDE like `SQL Developer` or `TOAD`, you can execute the Query and Export it.

3) But for PL/SQL

**test_dir** mentioned below, is a directory in the host machine , accessible to Oracle. It should be listed in *ALL_DIRECTORIES* dictionary table.

```
DECLARE
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  cursor emp_cursor is select employee_id,employee_name,employee_age FROM employee;
  TYPE emp_type IS TABLE OF emp_cursor%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  l_emp_type emp_type;
  v_fetch_limit NUMbER := 10000;
BEGIN
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('test_dir', 'sql_output.txt', 'W',max_linesize => 4000);
  open emp_cursor;
  LOOP
      FETCH emp_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO l_emp_type LIMIT v_fetch_limit;
      EXIT WHEN l_emp_type.COUNT < v_fetch_limit;
      // Used to control the fetch size.
      FOR I IN 1..l_emp_type.COUNT LOOP
          UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, '%s|%s|%s',l_emp_type(I).employee_id,
                                               l_emp_type(I).employee_name,
                                               l_emp_type(I).employee_age);
      END LOOP;
      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(fileHandler);//Flush the buffer to file
  END LOOP
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
  IF(emp_cursor%ISOPEN) THEN
       emp_cursor.close();
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_file.invalid_path THEN
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'ERROR: Invalid PATH FOR file.');
     IF(emp_cursor%ISOPEN) THEN
         emp_cursor.close();
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Finally, copy it from the UTL_FILE directory in Server.
The directory may be a NAS mount too. Just the Oracle need to have write access to it.

4) Like a PL/SQL, a Pro*C program, or Any OCI interface too will work! Generally, Options 3 and 4 gives you good control in the process you do!

Good Luck!

**EDIT:** Added improvements over fetch size and flushing

Comment: I am getting Invalid Path for file ORA-06512 error

Comment: can you do `select * from all_directories;`

Comment: instead of `test_dir`, you have to use that name

Comment: do you mean I have to select anyone directory_name from the result returned by select * from all_directories query

Comment: yes, you cannot give the full path.. oracle will resolve it later.

Comment: but the path or directory name I am unable to find it in my local system for example directory_name DP3 and directory_path /expdumps/work/10g_rollback

Comment: then it is located in remote machine.

Comment: probably, you have to log into that machine. you can identify the machine name using the host mentioned in the TNS

Comment: OK LET ME CHECK IN MY REMOTE LOCATION IF THE FILE CREATED WITH DATA

Comment: Great, I followed the best practises to be followed with cursors and files..in my script. You can refer it too, to refine yours.

Comment: Is there any other option other than going with all_directories because the location of the folder's are at the database side and I dnt have access to there folder's

Comment: no, you have to get the privileges. DBA should direct you to the respective team. it is a one time work.! For now, you can ask them to ftp you, some where in common.